# "unqualified-id" compiler error when accessing member of a class through a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, void-pointers

I am currently working on a delegate class for use in several of my programs. My code for loose functions works, but I am getting a compiler error in the code that binds member functions. The compiler error contents are

> error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token.

I'm not seeing any reason why this would be the case. My code, excluding parts that compile nicely, is as follows:

```
template <typename T> class Delegate;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Delegate<R(Args)>
{
    typedef void* InstancePtr;   

//...

    template <typename C, R (C::*classFunction)(Args...)>
    static inline R MakeStubFunction(InstancePtr instance, Args... args)
    {
        //  vvv  error on this line  vvv
        return ( static_cast<C*>(instance)->(*classFunction) )(args...);
    }

//...

 };
```

Can anyone point out the source of the compiler error? In the interest of being able to solve such problems in the future, what is meant by "unqualified-id"?

Comment: "unqualified-id" means something like "some name", i.e. letters, no special characters like braces but rather a variable name, type name, function name, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the braces and use the `->*` operator:

```
return ( static_cast<C*>(instance)->*classFunction )(args...);
```

Comment: To assuage my curiosity (if you're willing) do you know *why* the syntax I used doesn't work? It seems like it should be valid...

Comment: @Conduit You can't "dereference" a pointer to a non-static member without an object, but that was what you tried to do inside the braces.

Comment: Ahhh - is this because the actual contents of the function might change based on the member variables contained in an instance?

Comment: A little upsetting if so... I figured that a member function would "know" the location of the member variables it needed based on the memory offset of the member variable from the first address used by the provided instance.